# Webpack and Gulp for React in 2021

Tags: webpack, gulp

What should we use for React applications in 2021, webpack or gulp or both?

As I understand, years ago webpack was only bundler and we had to use gulp to process scss to css and so on. But now when we have webpack 5 with all it features, is there any reason to use gulp? In webpack documentation they write that task runners like gulp are higher level tools and it could be useful to use them, what does they mean by these words? There is also a point that we can replace gulp with npm scripts, is really possible?

Now my purpose is to get understanding about should I use webpack only or combine it with something else and if combine then in which situations?
I have also fond similar questions, but they were like 5 years old and I am aware to make an incorrect choice in the begging of my way.
Any links to articles where it can be explained are also appreciated.